# How to expand this awk column 2 selector with Bash parameter $1?

Tags: bash, awk, csv

I am trying to make my bash script a function with Bash input parameter but AWK's syntax is causing a problem. 
Original AWK code

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19602188/54964
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' textfile.csv
```

Pseudocode with Bash parameter `$1`

```
file=$(awk -v colN="$1" -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $"${colN}"}' "${input}") 
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/19602188/54964 
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/19075707/54964
```

The problem is the part `print $"${colN}"`.

Current output fails to catch the second column and takes the whole line etc

```
-0.21,-0.245
-0.205,-0.22
```

Having only `print $colN` is not correct, since it takes then always the first column regardless of the value in `$1`.

Example of the use case where I call it by `bash code.bash 2`; or complete script [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23421523/) which works if you do not hard-code which column to choose (1/2) in all two-column CSV files for the joined result of second columns

```
#!/bin/bash
ids=(101 118 201)
dir="/home/masi/Documents/CSV/"
index=0
for id in "${ids[@]}";
do
        input=$(echo "${dir}P${id}C1.csv")
        # take second column of the file here
        file=$(awk -v colN="$1" -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $colN}' "${input}") # http://stackoverflow.com/a/19602188/54964 # http://stackoverflow.com/a/19075707/54964

        Ecgs[${index}]="${file}"
        index=$index+1
done
```

Inputs multicolumn 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv

```
-0.21,-0.245
-0.205,-0.22
```

Wanted output

```
101,118,201
-0.245,-0.245,-0.245
-0.22,-0.22,-0.22
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Bash 4.30

Comment: you are using the $ two times

Comment: it's a variable, as far as i remember, you don't need any $, you just refer to it as `colN`, and yes, to refer to the number of column, you use a $

Comment: tried using  `$colN` ?

Comment: @Masi, you're only asking for the second column to be printed.  Did you want the *first two* columns to be printed?

Comment: Why do you want the columns in a Bash array?  What's the actual final end result you want?

Comment: Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)  You might consider doing the *entire* thing in Awk, rather than using a Bash array.  But I don't know the use case.

Comment: to save the 2nd column form each file, `paste` is a better solution, a solution was provided earlier to you

Comment: @Masi, can you please provide a simple example input and example output?

Comment: Also, does your script actually *work* as written?  I should think you would want `>>`, not `>`.  If it's a working script, you might post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I will say this, though: I am absolutely certain that the entire script can be replaced with a single simple command.  I'm just having trouble telling what you are actually trying to do with the script.  So an example input and output would help a lot.

Comment: @Masi, but they're multi-column CSVs and you just want one column from each—right?

Comment: The example input/output is *really* bad.  Are the values *actually* the same for the first and second field?  Are there ever more than two fields in the input files?  I'm thinking `paste -d, /home/masi/Documents/CSV/P{101,118,201}C1.csv | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $2, $4, $6}'` but if there is ever more than two fields in the input files that won't work as expected.

Comment: @Wildcard I opened the thread about the script validity in the code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146360/122105 I think it would be better to replace AWK part from something else because it causes the strange problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bash and AWK in the case will be very hard. 
I could not solve the problem by the solutions proposed here. 
You are going to have much problems with `"`/`'`/... so a single tool is necessary here.

Use just `gawk` as discussed in the thread [ECG Bash selection tool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146370/122105).

```
# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146370/122105
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

# https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html
@include "join.awk"

BEGIN {
    FS = "\"*,\"*";
    last_row = 0;
}

BEGINFILE {
    rows[0][ARGIND] = gensub(".*P([0-9]*)C.*", "\\1", "g", FILENAME);
}

{
    rows[FNR][ARGIND] = $col;
    if (FNR > last_row) { last_row = FNR; }
}

END {
    for (r = 0; r <= last_row; r++) {
        print join(rows[r], 1, ARGC - 1, ",");
    }
}
```

Please, read the complete answer of `200_success` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146360/ecg-bash-selection-tool) with excellent explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Your example input has the same values in the first and second field for all files (and the same values for all files), which doesn't really help understand the exact use case.  After all, if you really want the same value three times and you can get it from any field of any input file, you don't even need to check the other two files.  You can just use:

```
cut -d, -f2 input.csv | paste -d, - - -
```

Of course this doesn't work for real input, just your example input.  (Work on improving your example input/output for this type of question, it helps a *lot*.)

---

If we make the assumptions that:

- You always have exactly three input files
- Called `input1.csv`, `input2.csv`, `input3.csv`
- With exactly two columns each
- And you want the second column from each file

You can do this most easily with a combination of Awk and `paste` (and shell file globbing):

```
paste -d, input[123].csv | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $2, $4, $6}'
```

---

If those assumptions are wrong, blame poor input/output examples.  ;)

Comment: Can you show me how you make this function because it is the main topic here? - - Etc take second columns of each file. - - I think the outputs are correct but the behaviour with Bash input parameters is my interest, etc with your last command.

Comment: Assume you have a list of inputs. This is not working as expected `paste -d"," ${input[@]} | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $2, $4, $6}' > /tmp/testShort.csv`.

Comment: @Masi, just list them individually.  `paste -d, file1 file2 file3 | ...`

Comment: @Masi, how are you setting the `input` array?  If you do `files=(file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv)` you can follow it up with `paste -d, "${files[@]}" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $2, $4, $6}'`.

Comment: `input` array is set like in the loop of the body. - - Is it equivalent to your `files`? Should I change the datastructure there? If so, how? - - This is the output from your proposal `-0.245,,` for the second line. Please, try to use Bash input parameters for the task, like I do.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as stated, given

```
$ cat file
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
j,k,l
```

and a simple test script

```
$ cat col.bash
#!/bin/bash

awk -F, -vcol="$1" '{print $col}' file
```

you can verify that `$col` indeed references the desired column i.e.

```
$ ./col.bash 2
b
e
h
k
```

If that's not working in your case, then there are other factors at play. Regardless, there are far simpler ways of extracting columns from multiple files.

Comment: I think this fails with the example data set. - - I think you really need `-F "\"*,\"*"`.